# Sortable list to update hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, hidden-field

I have an unordered list that is sortable using jQuery.  The sort function(s) works fine and is below.  Each list item has an id on this format-  id="post_#" where the # is a unique number.  I need to update the hidden input value with the order of the list items after they're sorted, but only the #.  So if the order of the items was >   post_3, post_2, post_4, post_1   < then the input value would be-  value="3,2,4,1"

Here's the jQuery I have so far-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("#wpbody-content #post_sortable_list").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: \'move\', update: function() {
                var order = $(this).sortable;

            }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And the HTML-

```
<div id="wpbody-content">
<ul id="post_sortable_list">
<li id="post_1">foo</li>
<li id="post_2">bar</li>
<li id="post_3">hello</li>
<li id="post_4">world</li>
</ul></div>

<input type="hidden" name="posts_order" value="" />
```

Comment: Just do `var order = $(this).sortable("serialize");` will return an array with the id being post and the result being 3,2,4,1 :)

Answer (score 1):

can you do something like

```
var order = '';
 $('#post_sortable_list').find('li').each( function () {
  order = order + $(this).text().substring(5);
});
$('posts_order').val(order);
```

possible i'm way off base

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("#wpbody-content #post_sortable_list").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: \'move\', update: function() {
                var order = $(this).map(function(i, e){
                    return $(e).attr("id").substring(5);
                }.join(", ");

            }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Try using map to get all the Ids and then joining them into a string.